# XML generate from SQL Query with perfect XML structure

Tags: sql, .net, xml

MY SQl "employee" Table Look Like

```
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
| Empid | Empname | Salary | Location |
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
|     1 | Arul    |    100 | Chennai  |
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
```

XML Generate from SQl Query:

```
select * from employee for xml path, root('root')
```

from this Sql Query I'm Getting My XML Files as given below

```
<root>
  <employee>
    <Empid>1</Empid>
    <Empname>Arul</Empname>
    <Salary>100</Salary>
    <Location>Chennai</Location>
  </employee>
</root>
```

But My Expected Output XML from SQL query as

```
<root>
<column>Empid</column>
<value>1</value>
<column>Empname</column>
<value>Arul</value>
</root>
```

Comment: The XML you're getting now is the much better one - clearly structured, self-documenting ......

Comment: But My Expected Output XML from SQL query as

<root>
<column>Empid</column>
<value>1</value>
<column>Empname</column>
<value>Arul</value>
</root>

Comment: @abirami that doesn't make it a good format. How would anyone find the *Empname* value int this? What would the XPath query look like? How would a .NET client deserialize this?

Answer (score 2):

As you were told already, the needed output format is really bad and erronous. Nevertheless this can be done quite easily:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(Empid INT,Empname VARCHAR(100),Salary DECIMAL(10,4),[Location] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES(1,'Arul',100,'Chennai')
                         ,(2,'One',200,'More');

SELECT 'Empid' AS [Column]
      ,EmpId AS [Value]
      ,'Empname' AS [Column]
      ,Empname AS [Value]
      -- follow this pattern...
FROM @mockup t
FOR XML PATH('employee'),ROOT('root');
```

The result

```
<root>
  <employee>
    <Column>Empid</Column>
    <Value>1</Value>
    <Column>Empname</Column>
    <Value>Arul</Value>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <Column>Empid</Column>
    <Value>2</Value>
    <Column>Empname</Column>
    <Value>One</Value>
  </employee>
</root>
```

But - by any chance - you should try to change this format. This is awful to query and will be your private headache for sure...

Some better suggestions:

```
<Employee>
  <Column name="EmpId" value="1" />
  <Column name="Empname" value="Arul" />
</Employee>
```

or

```
<employee id="1" name="Arul" />
```

or

```
<employee>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Name>Arul</Name>
</employee>
```

or (if you really, really want to stick with this), at least a column index like here

```
<root>
  <employee>
    <Column inx="1">Empid</Column>
    <Value inx="1">1</Value>
    <Column inx="2">Empname</Column>
    <Value inx="2">Arul</Value>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <Column inx="1">Empid</Column>
    <Value inx="1">2</Value>
    <Column inx="2">Empname</Column>
    <Value inx="2">One</Value>
  </employee>
</root>
```

The query for the last one is this

```
SELECT 1 AS [Column/@inx]
      ,'Empid' AS [Column]
      ,1 AS [Value/@inx]
      ,EmpId AS [Value]
      ,2 AS [Column/@inx]
      ,'Empname' AS [Column]
      ,2 AS [Value/@inx]
      ,Empname AS [Value]
      -- follow this pattern...
FROM @mockup t
FOR XML PATH('employee'),ROOT('root');
```

Comment: It's Worked for me.SELECT 'Empid' AS [Column]
      ,EmpId AS [Value]
      ,'Empname' AS [Column]
      ,Empname AS [Value]
      -- follow this pattern...
FROM @mockup t .. here i need to mention my table column name. if my table contains 60 fields i need to mention my all columns here.is there is any simplest way for the best solution.

Comment: @abirami, No, there is not "simplest way", you'll have to type this in... Well, you might create the statement dynamically, but I doubt this will be simpler... However, if this solves your issue, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check. Happy Coding!